# Woocommerce API getting authentication error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm created WooCommerce keys (consumer key and secret with read/write access). Using postman I'm trying to get products.

Below is my URL:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1563344366&oauth_nonce=IscAPO&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=URuHSJkskksim/fY4ULcwJf82I
```

I'm getting the below response:

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties

But I'm able get my orders using the `wp-json/wc/v3/orders?....` url.

Comment: That sounds like a fancy way of saying 500 internal server error … have you checked the error log’s first of all?

Comment: I don't have details to access ftp/ssh. I have only api keys.